# What is the recommended way to stop a Visit?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have implemented my own Visitor. In one of my VisitXXX overrides I might have to abort the entire Visit depending on a certain condition.

What is the recommended way of doing so? Obviously I can just throw and catch that, but I am wondering if that leaves things in a weird state?

Comment: Whether it leaves things in a weird state depends primarily on your code.  You need to show us some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw and then catch it. You need to unwind the stack and that's the most straightforward method, even if it isn't *pretty*. But that's what ANTLR actually does behind the scenes when it needs to backtrack.

Just make sure you use an exception type of your own, so that real exceptions don't get interpreted as a cancellation by mistake.

As for the state, the visitor object does not keep any, so there's no need to worry about that. Take a look at the visitor's source code, there are no hidden traps in there. As long as your code doesn't introduce some state somewhere that may get corrupted, you'll be fine.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I am doing and my Visitor doesn't keep any state. I was thinking maybe there was a pretty way. :) Thanks for the confirming.